# Firebase is not installing using npm i firebase

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm, npm-install

I am building an app on react. For backend I want to use firebase. But whenever I try to install firebase it shows me the following errors>

npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@grpc%2fgrpc-js reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

I couldn't solve the problem. I am using ubuntu 21.04. Need Help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the Firebase CLI directly from Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).